# How to check radio button according to value retrieved from database?

Tags: jsp, struts2, radio-button, el, struts-tags

I have a JSP page where I am saving a form and value of the selected radio button in database. Now , I need to update that page, everything is being displayed, but the radio button are not selected.
I don't know how to show the previously selected radio button on my jsp. I am using Struts2, Java.

Jsp Code:

```
    <div id="patientCondition">
            <input type="radio" id="new" value="n" name="pSB.radioInnerSubjective" /><label for="new">New</label>
            <input type="radio" id="noChange" value="nC" name="pSB.radioInnerSubjective" /><label for="noChange">No Change</label> 
            <input type="radio" id="progressing" value="p" name="pSB.radioInnerSubjective" /><label for="progressing">Progressing</label>
            <input type="radio" id="notProgressing" value="nP" name="pSB.radioInnerSubjective" /><label for="notProgressing">Not Progressing</label>
    </div>
```

Suppose I get value of radio button as 'nC' from database, now how do i select second radio button automatically.

I tried:

```
<input type="radio" id="new" value="n" <s:if test="${patientSoapBean.radioInnerSubjective == 'n'}">CHECKED</s:if> name="patientSoapBean.radioInnerSubjective"/><label for="new">New</label>
```

But I am getting error:

```
Mar 28, 2013 6:07:54 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/patient_soap.jsp (line: 703, column: 44) According to TLD or attribute directive in tag file, attribute test does not accept any expressions
```

Comment: I think I need to add conditions to this, but I dont know the syntax.

Comment: The code doesn't show enough for a full answer.  As you loop through the different possible answers, you need to check if the saved value you retrieved from the database is set to the value of the current answer.  When it is, you need to add `checked='checked'` to the radio button's input tag.  There are a lot of ways of doing this.

Comment: Can you point me to correct syntax. as I am getting trouble figuring it out. i have checked, when I am getting values back from database it reflecting pSB.radioInnerSubjective='nC', but the second option (which is for 'nC' is not getting checked.). please help me with this.

Comment: Can you show more of your code, please?  For instance, how are you getting the answer back?

Comment: I use ${} to get value from action class via valuestack.   for e.g.    `<input value="${pSB.patientID }" style="display: none"
     name="pSB.patientID"></input>`

Comment: Hmm.  Are you using the correct prefix for the `<s:if>` tag?  Convention is usually `<c:if>` but it doesn't have to be, I suppose.  What I see looks reasonably correct (though I think it should be `checked='checked'`.)

Comment: I my Jsp I have defined it as follows: `<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
`

Comment: I have also added error in my question that i getting

Comment: Aahhh.  I was assuming JSTL tags.  I don't know struts tags, but some quick googling shows a lot of examples using `%` instead of `$` for the expression prefix.  `$` is for JSTL.  Further, I would expect if you use Struts tags for the input tags, they'll handle things like automatically checking radio buttons.

Comment: i tried but still I not getting my radio button selected `     <input type="radio" id="new" value="n" <s:if test="%{pSB.radioInnerSubjective == 'n'}">checked="checked" </s:if> name="pSB.radioInnerSubjective"/><label for="new">New</label>
`

Comment: You might also want to output the value of pSB.radioInnerSubjective to see if it actually would match.

Comment: I tried that too in a text box it displaying 'n' for the above case which is correct. The problem is `<s:if test="%{patientSoapBean.radioInnerSubjective=='n'}"> checked="checked" </s:if>` is not getting correctly executed

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  Sorry.

Comment: it might be a browser issue also..try to do just this
<s:if test="%{patientSoapBean.radioInnerSubjective=='n'}"> checked </s:if> 
Replace checked="checked" with just checked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use `${...}` inside Struts2 tags and you need to swap `'` and `"` in `test` attribute to correctly compare with one character string.

```
<input type="radio" id="new" value="n" <s:if test='patientSoapBean.radioInnerSubjective == "n"'>checked</s:if> name="patientSoapBean.radioInnerSubjective"/>
<label for="new">New</label>
```

And of course you need getters/setters for `patientSoapBean` and `radioInnerSubjective`.

BTW Struts2 has `<s:radio>` tag which will check selected radio button.